# Turn xtick and xticklabel back on in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm creating a game in Matlab as part of an assignment. I've created a countdown screen in a Figure window, so turned the x and y tick labels off. However, when the countdown is over I want to turn the y tick labels back on, so is there a way to resort to the default settings that were in place before I turned the labels off?

Code so far:

```
figure('Color',[0,0,0],'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
whitebg(1,'k')
axis off
for k=5:-1:0
    if k==0
        gotext={'Go!'};
        gotexty=text(10,10,gotext,'FontSize',60);
        pause(1)
    end
    axis off
    plot(10,10)
    timetext={[num2str(k)]}; %Create live text on side of Figure.
    set(gca,'xtick',[])
    set(gca,'xticklabel',[])
    set(gca,'ytick',[])
    set(gca,'yticklabel',[])
    if k~=0
        timetexty=text(10,10,timetext,'FontSize',60);
        pause (1)
        delete(timetexty)
    end
end
axis on
title('Lunar falling!')
ylabel('Height above moon (m)')
set(gca, 'xTick', []);
hold on
```

### Many thanks.

Update:
Tried adding the lines `set(gca,'xticklabelmode','auto')` and `set(gca,'yticklabelmode','auto')` immediately after the `for` loop and this didn't seem to work. The ticks are off as desired during the countdown, but I don't pick them up after as shown [here](https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t35.0-12/12002029_10153129610512844_2074311131_o.jpg?oh=14939ad9cc2b3380636dae0b0dbd9fe7&oe=55F4943E) and [here](https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xlf1/v/t35.0-12/11990737_10153129610732844_974114039_o.jpg?oh=3bad825e7e1d220e685aa0bca0fab91a&oe=55F4938A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ticks back on, you can use

```
set(gca,'xtickmode','auto')
set(gca,'ytickmode','auto')
set(gca,'xticklabelmode','auto')
set(gca,'yticklabelmode','auto')
```

This gives Matlab control on what ticks and ticklabels to use, which is the default mode. Note that when you executed `set(gca,'xtick',[])`, `set(gca,'xticklabel',[])` etc the `'xtickmode'`, `'xticklabelmode'` etc were implicitly set to `'manual'`.

Comment: Was just about to post that.

Comment: @luis-mendo thanks for your comment, please see my update.

Comment: @timmr002 Sorry, You also need `set(gca,'xtickmode','auto')` and `set(gca,'ytickmode','auto')`. Please see edited answer